# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file inside an if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a login/signup program where the user must type in credentials in order to make an account or enter.

But I have two problems though, **one** is inside the function 'sign_up()' if the user is attempting to make a pre-existing account it should print the 'This username is taken' statement, but that's not the case. It prints a Value Error called 'I/O operation on closed file' instead.

Then the second problem is, it doesn't print the credentials in a designated file called 'LOG-IN_DATA', it's basically where you store it.

Anyway here is the code:

```
 from class1 import Credentials


def sign_up():
    choose_username_data = input("Choose a UserName: ")
    choose_password_data = input("Choose your password: ")
    Credentials(choose_username_data, choose_password_data)
    data = open('LOG-IN_DATA', 'a+')

    if choose_username_data not in data:
        data.write(str(Credentials))
        data.write('\n')
        welcome()
        data.close()

    if choose_username_data in data:
        print("This username is taken!")
        sign_up()
        data.close()


def log_in():
    username_data = input("Enter your username: ")
    password_data = input("Enter your password: ")

    data = open('LOG-IN_DATA', 'r')
    data.read()
    data.close()

    if username_data and password_data in data:
        welcome()

    elif username_data and password_data not in data:
        print("Username or Password does not match or not recognized.")
        log_in()


def welcome():
    print("Welcome! You made it in!")


def login_or_signup():
    signup_var = ('Signup', 'SignUp', 'signup')
    login_var = ('Login', 'LogIn', 'login')

    prompt_user = input("Welcome! Would you like to Login or Signup?: ")

    if prompt_user in login_var:
        log_in()

    elif prompt_user in signup_var:
        sign_up()

    else:
        print("\nChoose 'Login' or 'Signup'")
        login_or_signup()


login_or_signup()
```

Sorry if the code is too long. I just want problems and potential ones to be eliminated as far as I am concerned.

**Anyways thank you in advance!**

Comment: The two major things I see are `if choose_username_data in data` should just be `else` (since those two conditions are exclusive of each other), and `Credentials` is a class. You do, `Credentials(choose_username_data, choose_password_data)`, then never save the value, then try to write the class to the file. It should be `creds = Credentials(choose_username_data, choose_password_data)`, then `data.write(str(creds))`. It's not immediately clear how either of these would lead to the I/O error though.

Comment: Let me try this first and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `with` statements when manipulating files. It handles flush and close automatically even when errors occur.
For example:

```py
with open("path", 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
```

instead of:

```py
f = open("path", 'r')
content = f.read()
f.close()
```

The problem with this line `if choose_username_data in data:` is that before, you also used data. The cursor in the file is at the end of this file. So when you ask a second time without setting the cursor back to the start of the file, it read nothing. That's why the 2nd statement never evaluates true.

With everything I told you, the sign_up function can be written:

```py
def sign_up():
    loop = True
    while loop:
        choose_username_data = input("Choose a username: ")
        choose_password_data = input("Choose your password: ")
        creds = Credentials(choose_username_data, choose_password_data)
        with open('LOG-IN_DATA', 'a+') as data:
            content = data.read()
            if choose_username_data not in content:
                data.write(str(creds)+'\n')
                welcome()
                loop = False
            # if choose_username_data in content:
            else:
                print("This username is taken!")
```

Comment: One question, do we have to close the data after the loop is done or has been read?

Comment: Also, I don't see any user credentials being written inside the given database but, the error is gone though.

Comment: no implementation of a datadase is made here but it can be done really easily and no it's the point of using a with statement